# IBM System i - Debug Server for RDi debugging doesn't work

Tags: debugging, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rational-developer-for-i

I recently read an article about debugging ILE programm within the RDi IDE. So according to several YT videos and articles on varios blogs I just have to create a object filter and a member filter for my rpg(le) source and the compiled program.

Then I have to use the context menu of the *PGM object and either start with an service entry point (SEP) or just debug the programm als "Batch".

RDi tells me there is no Debug Server started, so I opened a 5250 session, logged in and entered the command "STRDBGSVR". But still the debug server is not running according to RDi.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Edit:

Versions:

> Windows 10 x64
>
> RDI 9.6.0.3
>
> V7R2

I already installed the necessary PTFs but the debug server is not starting.
(IDE gets frozen and "un-freezes" after ~ 10 Minutes, but server is not started)

- I changed the port for the debugger from 8001 to 3001, same result.
- I started RDI as administrator, same result
- I also configured the winows firewall and allowed all programs related to "ibm", "eclipse" and "rdi" to pass the firewall for a domain network.

For RDi I installed the CL/Cobol/RPG toolset and skipped the Websphere part. Like some tutorials say I have to open the "server" view and create a new server. But this does not work, since I haven't installed the WebSphere toolset. Maby this is the reason.

Comment: Sounds like there might be a firewall preventing connection to the debug servers.  On the `Objects` node of your connection in RDi, right click and select `Verify Connection...`

Comment: verifying the connection tells me that the RDi and RSE PFT are missing
(PTF SI64924 and SI63708)

Comment: But the cal back worked?

Comment: Do you have windows firewall or some third party firewall turn on?

Comment: Callback Server is found and successfull (port 4300)

Comment: I'm in the same intranet as the power i system and windows firewall for domain is active but all related to IBM and eclipse has permission to pass the firewall

Answer (score 2):

There are two different ways to debug programs using RDi. The old way using `STRRSESVR`, also called `Batch`, and the new way using `SEP`. I prefer `SEP`.

To use `SEP` you can open your source in RDi by whatever means you desire. If the source already exists, and you know what it is, just use `Ctrl-Shift-A` and open the source file. Place your cursor somewhere in the source, preferably an executable statement, and open the right click menu. The bottom entry of the right click menu should be `Set Service Entry Point...`. Verify the info for your service entry point, and click `OK`.

If the SEP debug server isn't running, you will get a dialog to start the debug server. Click `Yes`. The `SEP` is now set up. I am using RDi 9.6. There was a time where you had to set up the debug server separately, and then you could use the right click menu. If you are on one of those old versions of RDi you should upgrade, RDi is a lot better now. But, in the mean time you can right click on any of the remote connection subsystems like `Objects` in RSE. Then from the menu navigate to `Remote Servers => Debug => Start`. Now you can try to set a Service Entry Point again.

From here you can run the program however you need to on your 5250 terminal, or by any other means necessary. This works for all jobs, including server jobs, SQL triggers, batch jobs, interactive jobs, even CGI jobs.

Comment: Think you're confusing `STRDBGSVR` and `STRSRVJOB` + `STRDBG`.   RDi debugging requires the debug servers to be running, but it doesn't matter if you start them via green screen `STRDBGSVR` or via RDi itself  `Remote Servers` => `Debug` => `Start`.

Comment: No, it's not that, I am thinking of the command that you use to attach a remote debug job to through RDi. I haven't used it for a while. Not since SEP became available. It could be that STRDBGSVR is not the command I am thinking of either. But the one I am thinking of is not used for SEP, but instead is used for the batch debugging in RDi.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't `STRDBGSVR`, but `STRRSESVR` that I was thinking about.

Comment: starting the debug server via RDi (Remote Servers => Debug => Start or setting a SEP) makes RDi crash (no response)

Comment: No errors? I have had authority issues, but that produces an error. Looking at the response above, I recommend that you get the missing PTF's.

Comment: after crashing this error is produced: https://gist.github.com/LasterOfDesaster/72fb01fd6703c3852ca985d5d1b8f776

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change the user the SEP is running under to the user profile that the application is running under.

One important thing to remember is this feature may not work depending on the operating system version of your IBM machine. I know that on 5.4, we cannot debug through RDi, and have to do it through green screen. This is most likely responsible for the missing PTF error.

To set an entry point and debug server jobs interactively in green screen follow the process described here:
https://www.itjungle.com/2012/10/03/fhg100312-story01/

Comment: Hi @dogmama!
The problem is not if the SEP is set correctly or not. After installing the needed PTFs, I can't get RDi running the debug server. when clicking Remote Systems -> Objects -> Remote Server -> Debug -> Start, RDi gets frozen, does not respond. When waiting for ~ 10 Minutes the IDE gets back to its normal state and is usable like before. But no Debug server is running.